# Random Forest: Class-specific Gini variable importance in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, gini

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
fit <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE);
fit.imp<-importance(fit)
fit.imp
```

columns 1-3 show the class-specific variable importance for the Mean Decrease Acuracy measure.
Note that for Sepal.Length, the class-specific VIs are lower than the Mean VI values for Accuracy.

I have two questions about the implementation of RandomForest in R:

1) How are the class-specific importances calculated (i.e., how is it possible for the class means to be lower than the total mean?)?  I understand the theory of how permutation accuracy is calculated, but I am not a mathematician so reading the raw equations doesn't help me much.  Any quick explanation would be much appreciated before I dive into the RF package source code.

2) Is there a way to calculate class-specific Gini metrics, not class-specific Accuracy metrics (the default)?  I really want to do this.  I was about to start trying to code a way to do it, but thought I would ask here first.

Comment: okay, I figured out my first question: the class-specific VI (%DecAcc) are just averaged to get the mean VI (mean decrease in accuracy), then each class and the mean, respectively  is divided by their standard errors.  If you set `fit.imp2 = importance(fit, scale=FALSE)` it is clear.  Any help with my second question, though, would be much appreciated!

Comment: why would you like a class specific gini metric?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Because I am really interested in how well the model discriminates one particular class--the others are interesting but less important.  And I am comparing random forest variable importance with variable importance from a single decision tree on the same data, and the gini metric is a common currency for both (i.e., they match up well for overall variable importance using the gini).  I would avoid using a decision tree, but it has advantages of interpretability and being MUCH faster in prediction at the scale I am working at.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve a class specific gini-metric, you need to make a clear definition first. Is it computed by inbag samples and summed over OOB samples, like for VI, or what? You need to modify the source code of the package. In [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/does-breimans-random-forest-use-information-gain-or-gini-index/167153#167153) is explained where and how the gini loss function is computed.

I'm not sure you actually want this class-spcific gini metric to compare forest with single tree. Gini impurity is already quite unstable across the entire forest. If computed for a single tree and split over many classes, it would be even more unstable.

No model is fully black-box, check out partial dependence plots from randomForest package itself or the extended version [ICEbox](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ICEbox) for interactions([article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6392)).

Concerning speed. If you train 50 trees with reduced bootstrap *sampsize*, it usually only takes a few ms to predict. Do you really need to go faster? If so, consider to predict directly with the native c function from a non R environment.

Also here's a small example from my own package forestFloor of how to interpret a RF model trained on the iris data. The iris data set is very simple to visualize, because the features do not interact much.

```
library(forestFloor)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1)
data(iris)
X = iris[,names(iris)!="Species"]
y = iris[,"Species"]
rf = randomForest(X,y,
                     keep.inbag = T, #mandatory
                     replace=F,      #if true use, trimTrees::cinbag
                     importance=T)   #recomended
ff   = forestFloor(rf,X)
plot(ff,colLists = list('#DD101060','#10DD1060','#1010DD60'),plot_GOF=T)
#colours are individual classes
#y-axis is the additive change change of predicted probability as a function of separate feature values.
#x-axis is individual feature values
#lines quantify goodness-of-fit, that is how well the model could be explained in these 2D visualiations
```

[image]