# Does Breiman's randomForest function in R use Gini score or entropy score or Classification Error rate to decide the splits?

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I have read the R documentation on randomForest but I could not find anything about Gini or Entropy in it.
Is there a way to direct the train function of caret to use Gini score?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Breiman's random forest use information gain or Gini index?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144818/does-breimans-random-forest-use-information-gain-or-gini-index)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59177460/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger while it does clarify that caret does not use Gini score exactly but second part of my question is unanswered. I was wondering if there's a way to instruct train function to use Gini score for splitting?